# setTimeout triggering too quickly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tooltip(which is just a div) that appears when on the mouseover event of another element.
I am trying to make the tooltip hidden on the mouseleave event of the the main element, however, I want the tooltip to remain visible if the mouse is over the tooltip.

The tooltip is being position directly underneath its element.

My code is as follows:

```
var option_hide_timeout;

$(".option").mouseover(function () {
    showTooltip($(this));
});
$(".option").mouseleave(function () {
    option_hide_timeout = setTimeout(hideTooltip(), 2000); // delay the hiding to allow the mouse to enter the tooltip
});
$("#option_tt").mouseenter(function () {
    clearTimeout(option_hide_timeout);
});
$("#option_tt").mouseleave(function () {
    hideTooltip();
});

function showTooltip(parent) {
    var parentPos = parent.position();
    $("#option_tt").css({
        visibility: "visible",
        left: parentPos.left,
        top: parentPos.top + $(parent).height()
    });
}
function hideTooltip() {
    $("#option_tt").css("visibility", "hidden");
}
```

The problem is that the tooltip hides immediately after the mouse leaves the main element.
The problem is persistent across Chrome, Firefox, Opera and IE.

No matter what the value of the delay(2000 in my code is just an example, it would more likely be shorter in practise), it triggers immediately.

I have tried using both mouseover/mouseout and mouseenter/mouseleave - both produce the same results, which leaves me with the conclusion that the line:

setTimeout(hideTooltip(), 2000);

is not correct.

Placing an alert in the mouseleave event assures me that the code is being called.

Am I missing something obvious?  If so, a pointer in the correct direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
option_hide_timeout = setTimeout(hideTooltip(), 2000);
```

to

```
option_hide_timeout = setTimeout(hideTooltip, 2000);
```

The added parenthesis makes the function being immediately called instead of being given to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thank you.  This also works and is more elegant than what I posted as a follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed my own issue.

```
$(".option").mouseleave(function () {
    option_hide_timeout = setTimeout(hideTooltip(), 2000); // delay the hiding to allow the mouse to enter the tooltip
});
```

should be:

```
$(".option").mouseleave(function () {
    option_hide_timeout = setTimeout(function () { hideTooltip() }, 2000);
});
```

It was very simple and I *should* have realised this before posting.